# Do ESLint on a console to check if all files of a project are fine

Tags: javascript, console, jslint, eslint

I just installed **ESLint** and created a package.json for my project (which is an meteor project).

```
npm install -g eslint
```

Now I would like to test all my `*.js`-files in my project folder. How do I do that?

I tried to do

```
cd project
eslint -c package.json *.js
```

But nothing is happening.

At the end I want to do a test, if all files are ok, so I can do a merge / deploy or what so ever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eslint app-directory/`

The `-c` lets you define a config file, though the `package.json` won't serve as a valid eslint config.

This is a example eslint conifg: https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/es6.js

You just can create a `.eslintrc` file from where you execute your `eslint` command and it will use it as a default config (without you specifying it via `-c`)

Comment: Is it possible to exclude all `*.min.js` files?

Comment: Yep, just add an .eslintignore file